# FFMPEG build error

Tags: build, ffmpeg, mingw, avcodec

I've been trying to build a LGPL copy of ffmpeg and I have tried various different configure methods. I downloaded the latest source from the ffmpeg site and used the following simple configure

```
./configure --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --disable-static
```

However every time I try to build it I only end up with "avdevice-53.dll" and the error message like this

```
install: cannot stat 'libavdevice/avdevice.lib' : No such file or directory
make: *** [install-libavdevice-shared] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: He is trying to **build** source, not sure if SO would be a good place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be safe to ignore that error? Have you checked the source folder in the corresponding folders for the dll files?

```
 e.g. avcodec.dll - source folder/libavcodec
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem with wine. This is handy if you need to build ffmpeg on Linux for Visual Studio target.

First, you need to get lib.exe, link.exe, mspdb100.dll and msvcr100.dll files form Visual Studio installation path.

Rename to lib.exe to lib_vs.exe. And create a script file lib.exe calling lib_vs.exe:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine lib_vs.exe
```

Put all these files in you're build directory and set PATH able to find it.

I share the script i use to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    export PATH=.:$PATH
    rm -rf build
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cp ../lib.exe .
    cp ../lib_vs.exe .
    cp ../link.exe .
    cp ../ms*.dll .
    ../src/configure --enable-memalign-hack --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --enable-shared --prefix=../release --pkg-config=pkg-config
    make && make install
    cd ..
)
```